# How to give static internal IPs to an internal AWS NLB via K8S Annotations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to deploy an nginx controller with internal and external loadbalancers so far so easy and everything works.

Now i've got new requirements where 1 is to **fixate the IP's internal NLB gets within the VPC**.

So far i tried these annotations

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 'true'
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-private-ipv4-addresses: 172.30.12.11,172.30.11.12,172.30.10.13
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: subnet-asdf1,subnet-asdf2,subnet-asdf3
```

I've read that the IP's need to be in the same order as the subnets are which i did, but so far without any luck.